# Pandas extract the first year from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have this large data frame and I need to when certain resource are available for the first time. Let me explain it from my code.

```
df1 = df[df['Resource_ID'] == 1348]
df1 = df1[['Format', 'Range_Start', 'Number']]
df1["Range_Start"] = df1["Range_Start"].str[:7]
df1 = df1.groupby(['Format', 'Range_Start'], as_index=True).last()
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
df1 = df1.unstack()
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()

df2 = df1[1:4].sum(axis=0)

df2.name = 'sum'
df2 = df1.append(df2)

df3 = df2.T[['entry', 'sum']].copy()
df3.index = pd.to_datetime(df3.index)
```

Now print`(df3.first('1D'))` gives the following output:

```
Format     entry  sum
Range_Start            
2011-07-01      97   72
```

I can now see that Resource_ID 1348 first occurs on 2011-07-01, how do I extract only the Year from this information?

This is my sample input csv data:

```
Access_Stat_ID,Resource_ID,Range_Start,Range_End,Name,Format,Number,Matched_URL
1,15,"2009-03-01 00:00:00","2009-03-31 23:59:59","Mar 2009","entry",3,""
203,13,"2009-04-01 00:00:00","2009-04-30 23:59:59","Apr 2009","entry",18,""
204,13,"2009-04-01 00:00:00","2009-04-30 23:59:59","Apr 2009","pdf",7,""
```

Comment: Can you add sample input data? The best [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure, I will edit the question accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems need:

```
first_year = df3.index.year[0]
```